# I would like to create a Simple Http server in android

Tags: android, http, server

I have used the https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd code for reference. 
When i ran my simple android application. I am getting "application not supported" error.  While running my android application in eclipse.

My main activity code is :

```
package com.example.nanoservertest;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidWebServerActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int PORT = 8085;
  private TextView hello;
  private MyHTTPD server;
  private Handler handler = new Handler();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   // hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("inside resume");
 try {
      server = new MyHTTPD();
      server.stratServer();
      //server.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {
    public MyHTTPD() throws IOException {
      super(PORT);
    }

    //Start
    public void stratServer(){
    ServerRunner.run(MyHTTPD.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        Method method = session.getMethod();
        String uri = session.getUri();
        System.out.println(method + " '" + uri + "' ");

        String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
        Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
        if (parms.get("username") == null)
            msg +=
                    "<form action='?' method='get'>\n" +
                            "  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" +
                            "</form>\n";
        else
            msg += "<p>Hello, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";

        msg += "</body></html>\n";

        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

And My Server runner class is

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ServerRunner {
    public static void run(Class serverClass) {
        try {
            executeInstance((NanoHTTPD) serverClass.newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void executeInstance(NanoHTTPD server) {
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't start server:\n" + ioe);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Server started, Hit Enter to stop.\n");

        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }

        server.stop();
        System.out.println("Server stopped.\n");
    }
}
```

I am unable to start my application.

Comment: "application not supported" where did you get it?

Comment: post your code and log cat please

Comment: I have uploaded my code .. Help what i have missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this library, it seems to respond to your needs:
[AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync#androidasync-also-lets-you-create-simple-http-servers)